# F sharp KMP Algorithm is stuck in the first while loop if i use a pattern with the same characters at the first two indces

Tags: f#, knuth-morris-pratt

I am playing around with the KMP algorithm in f sharp. While it works for patterns like "ATAT" (result will be [|0; 0; 1; 2;|]) , the first while loop enters a deadlock when the first 2 characters of a string are the same and the 3rd is another, for example "AAT".

I understand why: first, i gets incremented to 1. now the first condition for the while loop is true, while the second is also true, because "A" <> "T". Now it sets i to prefixtable.[!i], which is 1 again, and here we go.

Can you guys give me a hint on how to solve this?

```
let kMPrefix (pattern : string) = 

    let (m : int) = pattern.Length - 1
    let prefixTable = Array.create pattern.Length 0
    // i : longest proper prefix that is also a suffix 
    let i = ref 0

    // j: the index of the pattern for which the prefix value will be calculated
    // starts with 1 because the first prefix value is always 0

    for j in 1 .. m do

        while !i > 0 && pattern.[!i] <> pattern.[j] do

            i := prefixTable.[!i]

        if pattern.[!i] = pattern.[j] then

            i := !i+1           


        Array.set prefixTable j !i  

    prefixTable
```

Comment: I haven't used the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm before, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm suggests that the value in the first index should be -1 rather than 0, because a mismatch at the very start of the string is a special case. Would that solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to repair the code with a small modification, since it doesn't match the KMP algorithm's lookup table contents (at least the ones I've found on Wikipedia), which are:

- -1 for index 0
- Otherwise, the count of consecutive elements before the current position that match the beginning (excluding the beginning itself)

Therefore, I'd expect output for `"ATAT"` to be `[|-1; 0; 0; 1|]`, not `[|0; 0; 1; 2;|]`.

This type of problem might be better to reason about in functional style. To create the KMP table, you could use a recursive function that fills the table one by one, keeping track of how many recent characters match the beginning, and start running it at the second character's index.

A possible implementation:

```
let buildKmpPrefixTable (pattern : string) =
    let prefixTable = Array.zeroCreate pattern.Length

    let rec run startIndex matchCount =
        let writeIndex = startIndex + matchCount
        if writeIndex < pattern.Length then
            if pattern.[writeIndex] = pattern.[matchCount] then
                prefixTable.[writeIndex] <- matchCount
                run startIndex (matchCount + 1)
            else
                prefixTable.[writeIndex] <- matchCount
                run (writeIndex + 1) 0
    run 1 0
    if pattern.Length > 0 then prefixTable.[0] <- -1
    prefixTable
```

This approach isn't in danger of any endless loops/recursion, because all code paths of `run` either increase `writeIndex` in the next iteration or finish iterating.

*Note on terminology: the error you are describing in the question is an endless loop or, more generally, non-terminating iteration. Deadlock refers specifically to a situation in which a thread waits for a lock that will never be released because the thread holding it is itself waiting for a lock that will never be released for the same reason.*

Comment: Your code works like a charm, thank you! I used this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ogqPWJSftE), where they used an array that starts with the index 1 instead of 0, and i tried to change that in my code, which probably led to some mistakes. Also, TIL what a deadlock is. Thank you for your post.